# how can i ask add more than 1 list

Tags: python, function

Kids who are enthusiastic about collecting marbles, want to play a different game with them.

After having a long discussion and making sure that each kid will play the game with equal number of marbles, they finally agree on the following rules:

Each "black" marble gives 3 point.
Each "red" marble gives 5 points.
Each "silver" marble gives 7 points.
While looking through the marbles of a kid, if a "white" marble is seen, the scoring will be over for that kid, and he/she will not be able to take any points for the rest of his/her marbles (including the "white" one).
Each marble with another color gives 2 point.
At the end of the game, the kid who got the greatest total points will be the winner. In case of a tie, the kid whose marbles are scored later, will be the winner.
Write a function named marble_game which takes a list of lists of strings where each list represents a kid's marbles. This function must return a list that consists of a list of strings and an integer which are the marbles of winner kid and the total points of this kid respectively.

Note that the number of the kids and the number of a kid's marbles in the game may differ in the different plays of the game.

I have example like that but i cant add more than one list to function how can i fix it or how can i solve this example

```py
def marble_game(**kwargs,**args):
    points=0

    for i in liste:
        if i=="black":
            points+=2

        elif i=="red":
            points+=5

        elif i=="silver":
            points+=7

        #return points
        return points

#print(marble_game(["red","red","silver"]))
print(marble_game(["red","red","silver"],["blue","blue","blue"]))
```

Comment: my code not working like that when i write def marble_game(list) i can  use only one list in function, someone can help me for solve this :/

Comment: You pass two parameter but use one. that's why it's getting error

Comment: but i dont know how mant parameter i can use example i can add 10 list or 4 list how can i say this to my function?

Comment: Make it one argument and give it one list containing all the marble lists

Comment: no i want give 3-4 list example like that  marble_game(["blue","red"],["black","red"] or it can be 10 list or can be 4 list

Comment: Then you would need optional arguments.

Comment: @Origami25 The question tells you the function must take "a list of lists of strings". So your function will need nested for-loops, wtih the outer one iterating over the lists, and the inner one iterating over the marbles in each list. And note that thye return value must be "a list that consists of a list of strings and an integer".

Answer (score 2):

Try *args for many arguments

```
def marble_game(*args):
    points = 0
    for item in args:
        for i in item:
            if i == "black":
                points += 2

            elif i == "red":
                points += 5

            elif i == "silver":
                points += 7
    return points

print(marble_game(["red","red","silver"]))
print(marble_game(["red", "red", "silver"], ["blue", "blue", "blue"]))
```

For the highest value of the lists - store the value always in "points" and overwrite once a list has a higher value:

```
        def marble_game(*args):
            points = 0
            for item in args:
                current = 0
                for i in (item):
                    if i == "black":
                        current += 2

                    elif i == "red":
                        current += 5

                    elif i == "silver":
                        current += 7
                if current > points:
                    points = current
            return points
```

And on the very last note :) you might want to cosider keeping your scores in a dictionary - as your if statements would grow it makes it a little hard to read your code...

```
        def marble_game(*args):
            points = 0
            score_dict = {'black': 2,
                          'red' : 5,
                          'silver' : 7}

            for item in args:
                current = 0
                for i in item:
                    current += score_dict.get(i, 0)
                if current > points:
                    points = current
            return points
```

Comment: but second is giving 0 i need this give value which have most point

Comment: For that you need to store that somewhere let me edit the post

Comment: okay i understand thank u very much i posted some code down can u look is it true

Answer (score 1):

This code uses [Arbitrary Arguments (*args)](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_arbitrary_arguments.asp) to get the input and then a dictionary to store all the data.

```
def marble_game(*list_of_kids):
    # store all kids' results along with their marbles
    scores = {}
    for kids_marbles in list_of_kids:
        # reset score for everyone
        points = 0
        for i in kids_marbles:
            if i == "black":
                points += 3
            elif i == "red":
                points += 5
            elif i == "silver":
                points += 7
            elif i == "white":
                scores[points] = kids_marbles
                # stop counting
                break
            # every other color scores 2
            else:
                points+=2
        # save score
        scores[points] = kids_marbles
    # return the max score
    max_score = max(scores.keys())
    return scores[max_score], max_score


print(marble_game(["red","red","silver"]))
print(marble_game(["red", "red", "silver"], ["blue", "blue", "blue"]))
# output
(['red', 'red', 'silver'], 17)
(['red', 'red', 'silver'], 17)
```

Comment: oh yes i think it is working but only can i do like that?  if there have one white in list i can turn all point to 0   because when there have white in ball it ll turn score to 0

Comment: dear friend i just did  elif=="white" points==0 and it worked i think i posted in down can u look thank u

Comment: @Origami25 yep, seems so. But actually that is not what the texts in your question says. It asks you to stop counting, not to reset the score.

Comment: ah okay sorry i want do that question with bad english my english is not perfect :) hey and you did dictionart for store data yes?

Comment: @Origami25 Yes, dictionaries can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # store all kids' results along with their marbles
    scores = {}
    for kids_marbles in list_of_kids:
        # reset score for everyone
        points = 0
        for i in kids_marbles:
            if i == "black":
                points += 3
            elif i == "red":
                points += 5
            elif i == "silver":
                points += 7
            elif i == "white":
                points = 0
                # stop counting
                break
            # every other color scores 2
            else:
                points+=2
        # save score
        scores[points] = kids_marbles
    # return the max score
    max_score = max(scores.keys())
    return scores[max_score], max_score


print(marble_game(["red","red","silver"]))
print(marble_game(["red", "red", "silver"], ["blue", "blue", "blue","silver","black","black"],["silver","silver","silver","white","red"]))
```

Comment: This seems good - but be mindful that in case two lists end up to score the same number the one later taken into account will overwrite the other - I  think this is what is mentioned in your description - just be mindful that you scores dict might not have the same number of records as many lists you pass in as you are making the score the key

Comment: ah okay i understand thank u dear Anna even i finished python course but it was really so hard for me if you and another friend wouldnt help me i couldnt do anything

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, then please click the checkmark next to it. This will help future readers.